# Detect when left click is down without using GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c#

I have a program is left clicking when i have left click down but i don't know why **mouse_event** (event i use for click) also interact with **GetAsyncKeyState** so when my click is down it execute the function for click but **GetAsyncKeyState** now know think my click is not down

- Console app
- NET 5.0

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    [Flags]
    enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
    }

    // If click left is down
    public bool IsLeftMouseDown()
    {
        return (GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) & 0x8000) != 0;
    }

    // If click right is down
    public bool IsRightMouseDown()
    {
        return (GetAsyncKeyState(0x02) & 0x8000) != 0;
    }

    // Simulate a left click
    public void LeftClick()
    {
        mouse_event((int)MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event((int)MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    void loop()
    {
        // When this is enable GetAsyncKeyState think i'm not holding my click anymore
        LeftClick();
    }
```

Comment: When you program a MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP then the left button is indeed not down.  The code works just fine when you comment out that mouse_event() call.

Comment: [NET 5.0 will reach End of Support on May 10, 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/). 

Answer (score 0):

I just found some code which can detect mouse clicks in Console, and tested if this works (in .NET 6.0), and it does!:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace console8;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true) {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Left:{IsMouseButtonPressed(MouseButton.LeftMouseButton)}  Right:{IsMouseButtonPressed(MouseButton.RightMouseButton)}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetAsyncKeyState(int button);
    public static bool IsMouseButtonPressed(MouseButton button)
    {
        return GetAsyncKeyState((int)button);
    }
    public enum MouseButton
    {
        LeftMouseButton = 0x01,
        RightMouseButton = 0x02,
        MiddleMouseButton = 0x04,
    }
}
```

output will be something like (depending on your use of the mouse):

```
Left:False  Right:False
Left:False  Right:False
Left:False  Right:False
Left:True  Right:False
Left:True  Right:False
Left:True  Right:False
Left:True  Right:False
Left:False  Right:False
Left:False  Right:False
Left:False  Right:True
Left:False  Right:True
Left:False  Right:True
Left:False  Right:False
Left:False  Right:False
```